# Docker PostgreSQL query output

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have problems with querying my PostgreSQL running in Docker. What im doing is connecting to my db

```
$ docker exec -it my_db_1 psql -U postgres -d project
```

I have table block, which has id, name and size for example. My query is like:

```
SELECT * FROM block WHERE id=1
```

Where can i see my outputs?

Comment: if you `docker exec -it my_db_1 bash` and then `psql -U postgres -d project` and  `SELECT * FROM block WHERE id=1` does it show more?

Answer (score 5):

You get output to your terminal STDOUT.

You can get it in one step only by

```
docker exec -it my_db_1 psql -U postgres -d project -c "SELECT * FROM block WHERE id=1"
```

Comment: Or -f if you want to execute a sql file